# Is there any way to separate IRC networks in Pidgin's chat window?

Tags: 10.04, pidgin, irc

I am normally active in at least three different IRC networks, and I use Pidgin as my IRC client, with the vertical channel list like this:

[image]

Is there any way that channels from different IRC networks can be separated from one another, while still having everything in this one window?

Here's basically a mockup of what I'm looking for:

[image]

I don't like XChat or Irssi.

Comment: Are you restricted to using pidgin, or are you open to trying other IRC clients?  `xchat` (in the partner repos) has this functionality OOTB (out of the box).

Comment: I'm not restricted to using it, but I honestly prefer Pidgin because of its simplicity. I know it's not the greatest of IRC clients, but Xchat seems almost archaic to me, and Xchat GNOME isn't any better in my opinion.

Also, I'm already having to deal with the crappy Linux Skype, so the fewer chat applications, the better.

Comment: this is my opinion, but... "When in doubt, `irssi`".  Also, Pidgin is pretty much **not considered** an IRC client by many linux support areas, because it only very loosely supports the IRC protocol.

Comment: I use irssi when I'm in Windows because I'm often gaming and irssi is low on system resources, but I still like Pidgin when I'm in Ubuntu. Thanks for your opinion though :)

Comment: If you would also like to see something like this, please participate here: http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/14406

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there really isn't a way to do what you're asking. If there is I've not seen it and I've used Pidgin extensively. It just tosses the channels in one list and it's pretty much up to you to figure out what's what.

Answer (score 2):

You can try set conversations By Account 
[image: by account]

Comment: How do I go about doing this?

Comment: you can see it on the picture ;)

Comment: I want to keep everything in one window, but if there is no other option, I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: oh you mean in one window, sorry up to you